# How can I disable a button in Xcode? 

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am new to iPhone development.  I am building an app by using Xcode but now would like to disable a button.  How is this possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
myButton.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 10):

Via code:

```
myButton.enabled = NO;
```

If you're using interface builder there's an "enabled" option.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a Swift 3.0 solution:

```
button.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

button.enabled = NO;

you can set the button property to no and if interface builder you can uncheck the property

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.enabled = true;
```

this will ENABLE the button

```
button.enabled = false;
```

this will DISABLE the button.
If you want to hide the button you can do this

```
button.alpha = 0.0;
```

and if you want to show the button once more you can do this.

```
button.alpha = 1.0
```

Hope this helps! :)